# use color for richtextbox but error in con trỏ mouse when additional character characters

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

```
Private Sub Write_code_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Write_code.TextChanged
        Dim strWord As String
        Dim lPos As Long

        strWord = "read"

        lPos = InStr(1, Write_code.Text, strWord, vbTextCompare)

        If lPos > 0 Then
            With Write_code
                .SelectionStart = lPos - 1
                .SelectionLength = Len(strWord)
                .SelectionColor = Color.Green
                .SelectionStart = Len(Write_code.Text)
                .SelectionLength = 0
                .SelectionColor = Color.Blue
            End With
        End If
End Sub
```

This is my code, I have a problem that when I open the text again, it can not add the characters (can only add to the end of the text at the end of the text). Is there any other code that can help me.

Comment: Your title does not reflect your question details. Please update to avoid the question from possibly being closed.

Comment: I'm sorry. I've fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the selection at the end of the text with this ".SelectionStart = Len(Write_code.Text)" You could keep track of the last selection and set it back.

```
Private Sub Write_code_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Write_code.TextChanged
        Dim strWord As String
        Dim lPos As Long

        strWord = "read"

        lPos = InStr(1, Write_code.Text, strWord, vbTextCompare)

        If lPos > 0 Then
            Dim originalPosition As Long = Write_code.SelectionStart

            With Write_code
                .SelectionStart = lPos - 1
                .SelectionLength = Len(strWord)
                .SelectionColor = Color.Green
                .SelectionStart = Len(Write_code.Text) ' Or maybe put it here
                .SelectionLength = 0
                .SelectionColor = Color.Blue
            End With

            Write_code.SelectionStart = originalPosition
        End If
End Sub
```